# How to get the medium size post thumbnail url in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

What I figured out so far:

I have a query like this:

```
$categories=get_category_by_slug('my_category_slug')
$posts_array = get_posts( array('category'=>$categories->cat_ID, 'numberposts' => -1 ));
foreach($posts_array as $post_array){
    $queried_post = get_post($post_array->ID);
    //I can get the source file link this way: wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($queried_post->ID))
}
```

But the source file is just to big. Functions like `the_post_thumbnail( medium )` won't work for me because it's not just url. It's an url with image tag wrapper etc. So is there a way just to get the link to the medium (or small) size file?

It's also possible to set the post thumbnail size in the functions.php after the line with the theme support and post-thumbnail:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 300, 300 );
```

I didn't try that but I don't want to set the size of all thumbnails.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_array->ID), 'medium')`.

This will return you an array with URL, width, height and cropping mode of this image.

**EDIT:** Updating to add the full code:

```
$categories = get_category_by_slug('my_category_slug');
$posts_array = get_posts( array('category' => $categories->term_id, 'numberposts' => -1 ));
foreach($posts_array as $post_array){
    if( has_post_thumbnail($post_array->ID) ) {
        $image_arr = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_array->ID), 'medium');
        $image_url = $image_arr[0]; // $image_url is your URL.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx but wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_array->ID, "medium") and wp_get_attachment_image_src($queried_post->ID, "medium") didn't work

Comment: Ah, i see. $post_array is your post, and not your attachment. I've edited my code above - feel free to give it a try.

Comment: I've just tested it - it works. I've edited my answer above to show you the full code that you should use. The `$image_url` will contain the medium-size image URL.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I guess I used wp_get_attachment_image_src() the first time and was too lazy to var_dump it. It just didnt return a string. I used wp_get_attachment_url() of my old function the other times. I was confused, sorry. But you're right! It works great! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Does this need to be inside a loop?

Comment: @DrunkenMaster no - you just have to make sure that you're using the correct post ID instead of `$post_array->ID`. In case you're in a loop, you can use `get_the_ID()` there.